# Calling a method from an imported class using the Import Type in TypeScript in One Line

Tags: angular, typescript, unique

Looking for a simple one line solution to calling a method from a utility class in a typescript file that is being used in its respective html file being called in an attribute.

**sample.html**

```
<blah> class="{{getString(string)}}" </blah>
```

**sample.ts**

```
import { BlahUtils } from 'blahUtils.ts';
/* This is the part in question */
getString(string).BlahUtils; or getString(string) = new BlahUtils;
```

**blahUtils.ts**

```
public static getString(string: string): string {
 return string.split('.').pop();
}
```

I saw an example before using a one line solution.  I am aware of the other options but I am trying to find a shorter solution to shorten the code so I don't have to create a new function in all the other ts files I import the utility file into.  I know there is a way to do it this way and am looking for someone who might have the answer.

Right now the best solution I have is

```
getString = BlahUtils.getString;
getString(string);
```

Is there a way to do it in one line of code?

Comment: @Drenai return a smaller string to the attribute in the html. The main question or solution I am looking for is how to call the method in the ts file using one line.  so something along the lines of getString = blahUtils.getString;

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a solution.

In the sample.ts file I am able to simply say

```
getString = BlahUtils.getString;
```

and that allows me to call the method directly from the HTML Attribute in the html file.